# WebDriver opens Chrome and shut down:Could not start a new session. Invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver

WebDriver opens Google Chrome browser and after few seconds it shut down by giving: UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new      session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

OS: Linux Mint
  Eclipse - Kepler

Following are things I did to setup chromedriver.exe in linux:

permission to /usr/bin/google-chrome:
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Apr 13 00:03 /usr/bin/google-chrome -> /etc/alternatives/google-chrome

permission to chromedriver.exe folder:
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 Apr 13 15:08 chromedriver.exe -> /usr/bin/google-chrome

Added /path/to/chromedriver.exe:

added below line at the end of the bash.bashrc file:
  export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/foldername

Following are the java code in Eclipse:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver.exe");
System.out.println( "*** Getting the chromedriver.exe path: "+  System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
wd = new ChromeDriver();
```

It is printing the correct path: /path/to/chromedriver.exe
It is opening a new chrome browser
Then it waits a while may be 10-15 sec and then shut down the browser with below message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'user-pc', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.5.0-17-generic', java.version: '1.8.0'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
    at testcases.CelerityWebSite.chromeBrowserTestCase(CelerityWebSite.java:372)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'user-pc', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.5.0-17-generic', java.version: '1.8.0'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:21203/status] to be available after 20020 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
    ... 36 more
```

Please someone tell me what is that I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: What version of Chrome & ChromeDriver?

Comment: Google Chrome version: 34.0.1847.116                       ChromeDriver version: 14.0.836.0